# Looking for a KVM switch capable of viewing 2048x2560

Tags: kvm-switch, high-definition

I'm looking for a KVM switch capable of doing a resolution of 2048x2560 resolution.  I've managed to find ones that are capable of doing 2560x1600 but those don't quite suit our needs.  Has anybody seen anything capable of running at such high resolution?

Michael

Answer (score 1):

Well i did find one, if price isn't a concern it is over $3k http://www.1800kvmswitch.com/Item/SPE-SL1.1-LC.aspx

Comment: I do like the phone number... 1 800 KVM Switch

Comment: Nice job!  Thanks!!  Reading the page through it looks like it might just be an extender.  A very cool extender though. :-)  Still, that's the closest link I have seen yet.

Comment: the 800 number may be worth calling, considering that is what they do, my bet is they carry everything you need, at a price of course. If 'multiplicity' works that is great! I have been using an (push-the-buttons) hdmi switch I ordered from Staples online and a second one I ordered at monoprice.com for good prices. I do not know the resolutions however.

Answer (score 0):

I came across Multiplicity by EdgeRunner which may fit the bill.  I'm waiting on a response from them to confirm that it'll handle my resolution needs.

http://edgerunner.com/multiplicity

It's comparatively cheap too, which is amazing.